# Whether to enter a Scottish address on a UCAS application to a Scottish course when gaining work experience+eligibility for it in England

Tags: scotland, residency

If one has resided in Scotland until graduation in Summer 2020 and worked in England since then for the purposes of gaining eligibility to a postgraduate Scottish course, is it permitted to enter one's Scottish address on the UCAS application in January 2021 for a September 2021 start? (Being ordinarily resident in Scotland on August 1 2021 qualifies you for free/reduced tuition fees in courses which begin in September 2021.)

Comment: Do you meet the requirements for being *ordinarily resident* as defined in the link from your other post on this subject? https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/59716/when-to-return-home-to-be-eligible-for-free-reduced-tuition-fees-in-an-accelerat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to return home to be eligible for free/reduced tuition fees in an Accelerated Masters starting a year after graduation in Scotland?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/59716/when-to-return-home-to-be-eligible-for-free-reduced-tuition-fees-in-an-accelerat)

Comment: I don't know enough to answer my own questions. Plausible scenarios: eg I am not ordinarily resident now because I pay rent in England but not in Scotland, and I need to get a job in Scotland by August 1 qualify by August 1. Or I am ordinarily resident in Scotland both now and on August 1 because I stayed/will stay there for the majority of both periods 28/01/2020-2021 and 28/01/2021-2022. Or maybe it depends on where I am registered to vote or which address I have registered with my bank. Or maybe you are not required to be ordinarily resident at the address you give to UCAS at all.